# Elasticsearch: Use a separate index for each language of the same data record

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data record which has a field called title. A record may have different languages for the title at the same time. Such a record has other fields whose values do not vary with languages and so I do not list them in the following two examples:

```
Record #1:
Title (English): Hello

Record #2:
Title (English): World
Title (Spanish): mundo
```

Currently there are four possible languages for the title: English, Spanish, French, and Chinese. There will be more languages supported when the system grows.

I am new to Elasticsearch. I think about having an separate index for each language. So for record #2, I will create two Elasticsearch documents (one for each language) and send a document to the index corresponding to its language.

Is this a good/acceptable design within indexing, update, delete, and search in mind? Any problems?

For this design, I believe it has at least benefits:

- I can easily decide how many shards are needed for each language
  independently
- I can decide the number and locations of shards for index (language)
- I can easily add an index for a new language when the system grows
  destroying or re-indexing existing data.
- The system can maximally  take advantage of distributed computing
  power

Thanks for any input!

Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution would likely work fine, but you can run into issues with duplicate documents if you start allowing multi-language searches.

It might be more optimal to have multiple possible values per field, eg:

- title.engligsh
- title.spanish

You can have completely different analysis rules for each language without duplicating the document.

This approach will further allow you to add a new title.whatever fields to documents with their own analysis rules. Be warned though, last I checked, if you use a completely new custom analyzer you need to open/close the index for it to take effect, which will result in a few seconds of down time.

I'll try to find some time to expand this answer with an end to end example.

Comment: ppearcy, thanks soooooooooooo much for chiming in!!! In my situation, title is the only searchable field. The issue of duplicate documents will be bad if multi-language searches is allowed? I am very interested in your one-document-multiple-value solution. A quick question: if the system grows, and I need to add a new language to the document. Will I be able to do that (introducing  a new field (e.g. title.russian) and specifying its analysis rules) without destroying the current index and doing another indexing for all documents? Again, thanks!

Comment: No problemo :) Added some more info to the response around adding new custom fields.

Comment: ppearcy, thanks a lot!!!. Do you have a paypal account? I would like to buy you a cup of coffee. Again, many many thanks!!!