# Elasticsearch: how to allow multi-language searches?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I posted a question called

Elasticsearch: Use a separate index for each language of the same data record

Here is the link: [Elasticsearch: Use a separate index for each language of the same data record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685864/elasticsearch-use-a-separate-index-for-each-language-of-the-same-data-record)

The posted answer mentions "allowing multi-language searches". I am confused about it. I read book "Elasticsearch server (2nd edition)" and did not see this topic. I just did a google search and was unable to see anything related online.

Does anyone happen to have any links about "allowing multi-language searches"? Is this a configuration thing? How?

Thanks so much for any input!

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don’t need to have different indexes for each language. Say you had a 'product' type that could have the title field in German or French or both, you would need to index the French title differently from the German title by using different analyzers. In your mapping specify what analyzers you want to use:

```
{
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "properties": {
                    "de": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "analyzer": "de_analyzer"
                    },
                    "fr": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "analyzer": "fr_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Index your documents

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/product/1' -d
'{
    "title": {
        "fr": "Bonjour"
    }
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/product/2' -d
'{
    "title" : {
        "de": "Hallo"
    }

}'
```

When you want to do a search on the French title you would reference it in the query

```
http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?q=title.fr:bonjour
```

When you want to do a search on the German title:

```
http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?q=title.de=hallo
```

If you want to search of both of the fields you can use a multi_field search:

```
{
    "query":{
        "multi_match" : {
            "query": "bonjour hallo", 
            "fields": [ "title.fr", "title.de" ] 
        }
    }
}
```

This blog will give you a good idea of how to use the analyzers for earch language you want to index:

http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/

Comment: Dan, thanks for the post. It is EXTREMELY helpful to me. My original post is about whether "allow multi-language search" means searching on multiple languages at the SAME time. And how to do that? Just do ?q=hallow+bonjour without specifying the field? I would like to know what "allow multi-language search" is, and whether it needs special treatment.

Comment: Dan, I cannot say enough thank-you for your help. Do you have a paypal account? I would like to buy you a cup of coffee.

Comment: Dan, I am going to adopt your solution. Just a quick question: When my system grows, I will add a new language. In this case, do I have to rebuild the entire index? If not, any pointer for how to incrementally add a new language into the mapping? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will have to re-index, but take a look at this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/. Thanks for the offer of the coffee. :)

Comment: Can I change "de": { "type": "string", "fields": { "de": { to "de": { "type": "string", "fields": { "default": {? (change the second "de" to "default"). I saw "default" used in the book. Thanks!

Comment: The default analyzer works well on the English language, it uses the Standard analyzer. If you were to use that for the German language, you might see some issues. One example would be sorting, using the default analyser for German would not sort the fields correctly because German has umlauted letters.

Comment: Dan, should I use "german" instead of "de_analyzer" and "french" instead of "fr_analyzer" in actual use of your mapping? Elasticsearch provides a number of language analyzers. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html

Comment: You could do, but if you use the ICU plugin (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-icu) as per the blog post I added you'd need to wrap the filters in an de_analyzer. Test both approaches out and see which one works best for your use case.